# Why CQRS Query side does not use ORM

Tags: nhibernate, domain-driven-design, cqrs

I read articles of  Greg Young from blog posts. I see that Query is getting data from database. We use Query DTO objects to fill **UI** screens. And recommanded that use a thin layer that includes plain SQL queries. Not recommanded to use **ORM** tools like **Nhibernate or EF**. Because of they use lazy loading so running multiple queries on database.
[image]

For example I have a **Order** screen. That should be show **Order** info and Order line items.

```
public class OrderDto{
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public string Date {get; set;}
   public IEnumerable<OrderLineItem> {get; set;}
}
```

To create an **OrderDto** instance, I should send a query to **Orders** table then send a query to **OrderLines** table. I think ORM tools will do same thing. So why use plain SQL and a new Thin Layer?

Comment: I think one round trip can be enough to get order & orderlines.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know the specific blog post or quote you are referring to, so I can't address that directly.

However the objection to ORM is that many projects use it for both query and command, *using the same objects*.  So if you are using an Order object for saving (command), and then when you want to show a list of orders on a screen, and do so by fetching a list of Order objects (query), you are probably not adhering to the basic principles of CQRS.

On the other hand, if you use an EF Order object for saving, but use an EF Linq query to project onto a list of OrderDTOs, I don't think anyone would object to the fact that you are using EF (or any ORM).

Answer (score 0):

"[...]Because of they use lazy loading so running multiple queries on database.[...]".
Well, no. You can tell to your favorite ORM not to use Lazy loading. In such case, you have good chances that two query are executed, exactly how you specify in the example.
BTW, the point is that, because you have two separate Commands and Query models, you are not forced to use the ORM to query the data store and so you shouldn't use it if you want to optimize your query service.
Instead, the benefits of an ORM are more evident at the Command side.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what are the reasons behind using plain SQL since the particular blog post is not included in the question.

In your example, you do not need two different queries to fetch both orders and order lines. Typically you could use a query with two tables joined (order and orderline), and same is supported by NHibernate.

When you are using an ORM like NHibernate it has support to do even better, with features like QueryOver / HQL, you can directly populate a DTO while fetching only required columns from the database. And in these cases lazy loading is not in play.